Wireguard macOS: Unable to update bind: listen udp4 :51820: bind: address already in use
When I put my laptop on sleep and the wireguard is open, after the resume, I cannot connect to the VPN anymore. Even if I close and open the app again.
It seems that the designated UDP port 51820 remains associated to some ghost process.
Below the error line from the log:
Unable to update bind: listen udp4 :51820: bind: address already in use

So, I tried to get the ghost PID, but:
Running sudo lsof -i :51820, I don't get any results.
Running sudo netstat -nav -p udp | grep 51820, I get the line
udp4     288      0  *.51820      *.*    786896    9216  69634

So 69634 should be the PID that I'm looking for, but when I run sudo kill -9 69634, the process does not exist.
This is the output:
kill: 69634: No such process

Can anyone help me understand what's going on?
ATM, the only way I have to solve the issue, is reboot the laptop and this is not acceptable.
Wireguard version.
App version: 1.0.16 (27).
Go backend version: 1e2c3e5a
OS version.
macOS Sonoma 14.5
